Merge digits into numbers within a list - part 2
I had a previous post which was answered nicely: Merge digits into numbers within a list
Unfortunately that example only listed single-digit numbers and now I am in a situation to join higher digit numbers same way for which the same solution does not work for:
FromDigits /@ {{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3, 45}, {4, 243}, {23, 45, 632}}

Produces:
{13, 17, 23, 3451, 75, 283, 3382}

Notice how the 3rd, 5th, 6th and 7th sets are incorrect. I would have expected:  113, 345, 4243 and 2345632 for them.
Yet it is actually doing:  {a,b}--> 10a+b
How can we correct this for "any" length number.

For reference, it's called concatenation not merging.

You do it with
FromDigits@*Flatten@*IntegerDigits/@{{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3, 45}, {4, 243}}

How it works: first convert all multidigit numbers to digits, then back.

Works amazing...Thanks!  What does the Astrix do? Gives unlimited length?

@* stands for function composition. The more conventional form would be
FromDigits[Flatten[IntegerDigits[#]]]&

This does not seperate them into lists:  FromDigits[
Flatten[IntegerDigits[{{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3,
45}, {4, 243}, {23, 45, 632}}]]]

I mean, you can use FromDigits[Flatten[IntegerDigits[#]]]&/@{{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3, 45}, {4, 243}} instead.

or using String
f = (# // Map[ToString] // StringJoin // ToExpression) &;
f /@ {{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3, 45}, {4, 243}, {23, 45, 632}}


Using Splice:
nlist = {{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3, 45}, {4, 243}, {23, 
   45, 632}}

nlist /. v_ /; v > 9 :> Splice@IntegerDigits@v // Map[FromDigits]

For versions prior to v12.2,
nlist /. v_ /; v > 9 :> Sequence @@ IntegerDigits@v // Map[FromDigits]



{13, 17, 113, 3451, 345, 4243, 2345632}

